# How to specify ObjectWrapper Freemarker

Tags: spring, freemarker

Help me please. My web-application uses Spring MVC and Freemarker 2.3.23. When I start my application, I have: "WARNING: Custom EL functions won't be loaded because no ObjectWrapper was specified" .  I have tried to specify ObjectWrapper in several ways like these:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFreemarkerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
@Autowired
public TaglibFactory taglibFactory(ServletContext servletContext) throws 
 IOException, TemplateException {
    DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder owb = new 
DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(freemarker.template.
Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
    owb.setForceLegacyNonListCollections(false);
    owb.setDefaultDateType(TemplateDateModel.DATETIME);
    DefaultObjectWrapper build = owb.build();
    TaglibFactory taglibFactory = new TaglibFactory(servletContext);
    taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(build);
    return taglibFactory;
}
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFreemarkerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public    DefaultObjectWrapper getDefaultObjectWrapper() {
    DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder defaultObjectWrapperBuilder = new 
DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(freemarker.template.
Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
    defaultObjectWrapperBuilder.setExposeFields(true);
    DefaultObjectWrapper defaultObjectWrapper = 
defaultObjectWrapperBuilder.build();
    return defaultObjectWrapper;
}
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFreemarkerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...
@Bean
@Autowired
public TaglibFactory taglibFactory(ServletContext servletContext) throws 
IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig = 
configFreeMarkerConfigurer(servletContext);

    TaglibFactory taglibFactory = freemarkerConfig.getTaglibFactory();

taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.
getDefaultObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion()));

    return taglibFactory;
}
...
}
```

but have not succeeded. Maybe someone has working example code to specify  ObjectWrapper?

Comment: Are you sure that Spring Boot even tries to inject those kind of beans into "itself"? I have seen that others define a `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean instead... so that's probably at least used by it. It's also the class that's broken in Spring; it should create and set up the `TaglibFactory` when both the `TemplateContext` and the `Configuration` is ready, and then it should call `taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(configuration.getObjectWrapper())`.

Comment: I meant `ServletContext` where I said `TemplateContext`...

Comment: I tried to do it in my  FreeMarkerConfigurer :    
        @Bean
        public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreeMarkerConfigurer() {
          FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
         configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/", "/WEB-INF/views");
            TaglibFactory taglibFactory = new TaglibFactory(servletContext);
            taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(defaultObjectWrapper);
            return configurer;}                                    
    but it doesn't work. I still have the WARNING. Could you give me an example of the code, please.

Comment: OK, see my *guess* as answer... But the code in the above comment surely doesn't work as you do not pass the `TaglibFactory` you have created to anything, so you are just feeding the GC with it.

Comment: BTW, FreeMarker 2.3.23 is old; upgrade it. It's not related to your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source code of `FreeMarkerConfigurer`: it recreates the `TaglibFactory` when it receives a `ServletContext`, but doesn't set its `ObjectWrapper`. So you need to override that method, and call `taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(configuration.getObjectWrapper())`. Note that I assume that `configuration` is always final there; I haven't checked though. (I do not recommend using an other `ObjectWrapper`, but the one that `Configuration` contains. So you need the final `Configuration`.)

Create an instance of your `FreeMarkerConfigurer` subclass, as a `@Bean`, and let's see if Spring MVC picks it up. (I don't know, I haven't tried.)

If it works, then this fix should be reported in the Spring Jira.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @ddekany,  for the answer, now my WebConfig looks like this:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "aquaplant")
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultObjectWrapper defaultObjectWrapper;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        resolver.setPrefix("");
        resolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);
        resolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
        resolver.setExposeSessionAttributes(true);
        resolver.setRequestContextAttribute("request");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/", "/WEB-INF/views");
        return configurer;
    }
    @Bean
    public DefaultObjectWrapper defaultObjectWrapper(){
        DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder owb=new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder
                (freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        owb.setForceLegacyNonListCollections(false);
        DefaultObjectWrapper objectWrapper = owb.build();
        return objectWrapper;
    }
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TaglibFactory taglibFactory(ServletContext servletContext) throws
            IOException, TemplateException {
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setServletContext(servletContext);
        TaglibFactory taglibFactory = freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory();
        taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(defaultObjectWrapper);
        return taglibFactory;
    }

    }
```

and I don't have any "WARNING", but on my registration page I can't get errorMessages. This cod don't work:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <@spring.bind "userForm"/>
          <#if spring.status.error>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
               <li>${error}</li>
              </#list>
            </div>
        </#if>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" 
            placeholder="Username" name="username">    
  </div>
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't know offhand, I'm not familiar with Spring MVC forms. But this is a new question, so open a new one. And you will have to provide much more concrete details (I guess your Controller method is relevant, and if you get an error message, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I just overrode getTaglibFactory():

```
import freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;

public class DefaultFreeMarkerConfigurer extends FreeMarkerConfigurer{
    @Override
    public TaglibFactory getTaglibFactory() {
        TaglibFactory tagLibFactory = super.getTaglibFactory();
        if (tagLibFactory.getObjectWrapper()==null) {
            tagLibFactory.setObjectWrapper(super.getConfiguration().getObjectWrapper());
        }
        return tagLibFactory;
    }
}
```

It seems to be working.